# How to wrap a row of the table when a checkbox in it is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a table in which I have to select a row when a check-box in that specific row is clicked. Only the row in which check-box is selected should be selected or lets say highlight it with red color. I have been trying to use a wrap function in JavaScript/jquery which is not showing any effect in my table. I had added the portion of code I was working. How do I do it?

```
Response.Write "<table><tr><td class='cell1'>Project</td><td class='cell1'>Project ID</td><td class='cell1'>Finish</td></tr>"
WHILE NOT rs.eof
    Response.Write "<tr><td class='celld'>"& rs(projectname") &".</td>"
    Response.Write "<td class='celld'>"& rs("productID") &"</td>"
    Response.Write"<td class='celld'><input var='"& rs("productID") &"' type='checkbox' id='finish' checked></td></tr>"
rs.MoveNext
WEND

<script>
    $("#finish").onclick(function(){
        $(".celld").wrap(" <div style='color:red'/>");          
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wrapping a `TD` element with a `DIV`? It doesn't sound right

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle `.highlight` class on parent(ancestor) `tr` when checkbox inside change it's state:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("table input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){

     $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight");

   });        
});
```

**Css:**

```
.highlight{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("table input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {

    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight");

  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
    <td>Select row
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
    <td>Select row
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td>Data 3</td>
    <td>Select row
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using jQuery, so it's actually quite easy. Attach an on change listener to the checkbox, and whenever a change is triggered, select it's parent `tr` element and apply a class to it.

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').addClass('hightlight');
});
```

Note that you also need this class to be defined in your styles, for it to actually, visually change the row.

Comment: There is no element with `checkbox` class in the document, you might want to include your HTML version in order for this to work

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues with your code. Firstly inside the loop you're creating multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, which is invalid. You should use a common class to select the elements. Also the `input` does not have `var` attribute, I presume this should be `value`.

From there you can attach a single event handler to all those elements which traverses the DOM to find the relevant `tr`. Note that the jQuery method to add a click event handler is `click()`, not `onclick()`. With checkboxes you should also hook to the `change` event to cater for those browsing via the keyboard. You can also set the class based on the state of the `checked` property of the checkbox using `toggleClass()`.

Finally you cannot wrap a `td` in a `div` as this too is invalid. It would be better to simply add a class to the `tr` which sets the required CSS rules. Something like this:

```
<table cellpadding="2" width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="tdcell1">Project</td>
        <td class="tdcell1">Project ID</td>
        <td class="tdcell1">Finish</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdcelld">Project Name #1.</td>
        <td class="tdcelld">ProductId #1</td>
        <td class="tdcelld">
            <input value="ProductId1" type="checkbox" class="finish">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdcelld">Project Name #2.</td>
        <td class="tdcelld">ProductId #2</td>
        <td class="tdcelld">
            <input value="ProductId2" type="checkbox" class="finish">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(".finish").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('red', this.checked);        
});
```

```css
.red { color: red; }
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rqmtcgab/)

Comment: Thanks it helped. I was wondering, will it be same if I have check-box in a div instead of it being inside td of a table. In other words, if I keep 'div' instead of 'tr' in above code, do you think it will work?

Comment: Actually I am trying to change the color for a whole div itself not for the font/contents of div only.

Comment: That's just a CSS change, use `background-color`: https://jsfiddle.net/rqmtcgab/2/

Comment: Ya I did background-color but the mistake i was doing was, I had another nested div so it wasn't highlighting the main div. Thanks @Rory for helping.